# Deploy Spark IM to all Computer In Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs, openfire

I would like to deploy the Spark IM client to all of the servers in my Domain from me Small Business Server. What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Group Policy](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Deploy-Applications.html)

But just to be sure, you want to deploy a chat client to servers???

Comment: Not to server to the Desktop machines.

Comment: If you have your desktops in their own ou, you should be able to push the client to that ou without too much issue.

Answer (score 0):

We run Spark in our environment. I found it very easy to deploy [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) (which is the xmpp server that the clients will connect to, they can't talk to each other without one) on a windows server on top of SQL server. It has been invaluable to us so far. We also use the Fastpath plugin for our site for live sales and tech support chat.

Check out the [Openfire install documents](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html), its super easy, and can be up and running (and integrated into AD!) within 30 minutes.

EDIT: Also, this is my interpretation on how to "deploy", unless you are looking for an actual way to push out the client.

Comment: I was looking for a way to push the clients.

Comment: I was looking for a way to install to all of my Desktop clients.

Answer (score -1):

It's a pretty straightforward domain push, but if you want the clients preconfigured, there is a really good howto on SpiceWorks using the free version of PDQ Deploy:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/113818-how-to-deploy-spark-instant-messenger

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.